# How to find recursively all links from a webpage with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to use some code I found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198934/how-to-get-all-links-from-website-using-beautiful-soup-python-recursively) to recursively find all links from a given URL:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com/"

def recursiveUrl(url,depth):

    if depth == 5:
        return url
    else:
        page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        newlink = soup.find('a') #find just the first one
        if len(newlink) == 0:
            return url
        else:
            return url, recursiveUrl(newlink,depth+1)


def getLinks(url):
    page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        links.append(recursiveUrl(link,0))
    return links

links = getLinks(url)
print(links)
```

and besides a warning

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 28 of the file downloader.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "downloader.py", line 28, in <module>
    links = getLinks(url)
  File "downloader.py", line 25, in getLinks
    links.append(recursiveUrl(link,0))
  File "downloader.py", line 11, in recursiveUrl
    page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 396, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think you're passing a BeautifulSoup object to `urlopen`, rather than the URL. Try something like `link['href']`, but be sure to check that it's present first.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but now I get an error "ValueError: unknown url type: /webpage/categery/general". Maybe because this is a relative link and not an absolute link?

Comment: @Alex correct: )

Comment: Have you considered just using `scrapy` btw? Does all the leg-work of following links to certain depths restricted to certain urls etc... for you...?

Comment: I tried 'wget' which did not download a single file

Answer (score 3):

Your recursiveUrl tries to access a url link that is invalid like: /webpage/category/general which is the value your extracted from one of the href links.

You should be appending the extracted href value to the website's url and then try to open the webpage. You will need to work on your algorithm for recursion, as I don't know what you want to achieve.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def recursiveUrl(url, link, depth):
    if depth == 5:
        return url
    else:
        print(link['href'])
        page = requests.get(url + link['href'])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        newlink = soup.find('a')
        if len(newlink) == 0:
            return link
        else:
            return link, recursiveUrl(url, newlink, depth + 1)

def getLinks(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        links.append(recursiveUrl(url, link, 0))
    return links

links = getLinks("http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com/")
print(links)
```

Output:

```
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/2017
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/2017/10
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/2017/09
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/2017/08
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/2017/07
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
http://francaisauthentique.libsyn.com//webpage/category/general
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will recursively go to every link and keep on appending full urls to a list. The final output will be a bunch of urls

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

listUrl = []

def recursiveUrl(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    if links is None or len(links) == 0:
        listUrl.append(url)
        print(url)
        return 1;
    else:
        listUrl.append(url)
        print(url)
        for link in links:
            #print(url+link['href'][1:])
            recursiveUrl(url+link['href'][1:])


recursiveUrl('http://target.com')
print(listUrl)
```